# Rails 3 Mailer Errno::ECONNRESET GMail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, smtp, actionmailer

I'm RANDOMLY getting the error:

```
Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer):
```

When trying to send an email:

```
UserMailer.activation(@user).deliver
```

In an initializer I set the smtp settings to use my Google Apps account:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "mydomain.com",
  :user_name            => "tyler@mydomain.com",
  :password             => "tylerspw",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Sometimes it works fine, other times it throws this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be something as simple as a timeout or excess server load on their end. I'd suggest rescuing the exception and retrying, then after a certain number of retries log the error and fail (or notify someone). Something along these lines

```
tries = 0
begin
  UserMailer.activation(@user).deliver
rescue Errono::ECONNRESET => e
  if (tries += 1) > 2
    retry
  else
   # log error
  end
end
```